# Filtering associative array based on two values

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array that contains academic subjects data which is :

- subjectName
- year
- semester

here is how it looks:

```
$subjects = array (
    0 => array (
        'subjectName' => 'Introduction to Programming', 
        'year' => '1',
        'semester' => '1', ),
    1 => array (
        'subjectName' => 'Introduction into Computer Science',
        'year' => '1',
        'semester' => '1', ),
    2 => array (
        'subjectName' => 'Computer Architecture',
        'year' => '1',
        'semester' => '2', ),
    3 => array (
        'subjectName' => 'Statistics',
        'year' => '2',
        'semester' => '1', ),
    4 => array (
        'subjectName' => 'DBMS',
        'year' => '2',
        'semester' => '1', ),
 );
```

I want to convert (modify) this array to a 3 dimension array based on the level (`$subjects['level']`) then the semester (`$subjects['semester']`).

Eventually i want it to look like this :

```
  $newArray = array(
    0 => array(
      0 => array(
        0 => array(
          'subjectName' => 'Introduction to Programming',
          'year' => '1',
          'semester' => '1'
        ),
        1 => array(
          'subjectName' => 'Introduction into Computer Science',
          'year' => '1',
          'semester' => '1'
        )
      ),
      1 => array(
        0 => array(
          'subjectName' => 'Computer Architecture',
          'year' => '1',
          'semester' => '2'
        )
      )
    ),
    1 => array(
      0 => array(
        0 => array(
          'subjectName' => 'DBMS',
          'year' => '2',
          'semester' => '1'
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

I've messed around with `array_filter()` but couldn't achieve anything.

Comment: I was able to filter it based on years using this code:

for($y = 1 ; $y < $years_count ; $y ++) {
          $filtered[] = array_values(array_filter($subjects, function($v) use ($y) {
     return $v['level'] == "$y";
}));
}

Comment: An image is worth one thousand words but not when it contains code. Use `var_export()` to dump the data and use copy & paste to put it in the question as text.

Comment: *"I want to convert (filter) this array..."* -- filtering and conversion are different things. [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) does not change the array structure, it just removes some items from the array. It is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: @axiac thanks for the information bro/sis, Yeah i think that code is more effective to post than images in this case , i was trying to make it simpler to understand (since i always find myself explaining stuff) , But most people who view this are programmers so code is the simplest form xD

Comment: If you post code or data in a form that can be easily copy/pasted and used  (i.e. as text) you have big chances to get an useful answer. If you post an image that contains the code all you get are down votes. I just retracted mine ;-)

Comment: Much love thanks for the information and tips again
I'm a newbie your tips are so useful :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about `array_filter` to get desired result. But you can use following trick.

```
$array = [
        ['name'=>'gg','year'=>'1','semster'=>1],
        ['name'=>'gg','year'=>'1','semster'=>2],
        ['name'=>'gg','year'=>'2','semster'=>1]
        ];
$newArray = [];

foreach($array as $arr){
 $newArray[$arr['year']][$arr['semster']][] = $arr;
}
print_r($newArray);
```

here is the running snippet: https://ideone.com/U2aX8r